# Discontinuous elevation contours at boundary of CanVec datasets

Tags: qgis

I am using Quantum GIS and I am working with the elevation contours from two adjacent CanVec datasets.  The problem is that many of the contours' endpoints at the shared boundary do not coincide with their counterpart from the other dataset.  I want to have these endpoints connected and then I want to merge the two datasets into one.  Can anybody give any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the contour lines being off a bit as well. Did you notice that some mapsheets have contours in imperial and some in metric? This threw me off for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above that is because some mapsheets that are beside each other display the contours in different units (metric and imperial). If you want to have your contours line up for these areas your best bet would be to create your own from dems available from the Canadian government. They are available somewhere in here:

http://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/

I forget where exactly.